# Get the word before & after '_-_' with REGEX PowerShell

Tags: regex, powershell, parsing

I am trying to get the Word before and decimal string following a non guaranteed string that looks like ' - '.

Consider this string

```bsh
"some str (targetWord - 12434 trailing string)"
```

this string is not guaranteed to have spaces before or after the '-'
so it could look like one of the following

```bsh
"some str (targetWord-12434 trailing string)" 
"some str (targetWord- 12434 trailing string)" 
"some str (targetWord -12434 trailing string)"
"some str (targetWord-  12434 trailing string)"
```

So far I have the following

```bsh
$allServices = (Get-Service "Known Service Prefix*").DisplayName
foreach ($service in $allServices){
  $service = $service.split('\((.*?)\)')[1]  #esc( 'Match any non greedy' esc)
  if($service.split()[0] -Match '-'){
    $arr_services += $service.split('( - )')[0..1]
  }else{
    $arr_services += ($service -replace '-','').split()[0..1]
  }
}
```

This works to handle the simple case of ' - ' & '-', but cant handle anything else. I feel like this is the kind of problem that could be handled by one line of REGEX or at most two.

What I want to end up with is an array of strings, where the evens (including zero) are the targetWord, and the odd values are the decimal strings.

My issue isn't that I can't make this happen, it's that it looks like crap...
what I mean is my goal is to try and use REGEX to get each word, ignore the '-', and push out to a growing array the targetWord & decimalString.

I see this as more of a puzzle than anything and am trying to use this to improve my REGEX skills. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: exactly what do you want from each of those sample data strings?

Comment: The data is supposed be pulled from the services running on my server, it's populated by another application. The data on the left is supposed to be a client's instance name and the right side is the port they are occupying.

Comment: you likely otta add to your Original Post the sanitized but _realistic_ sample data AND _exactly_ what you want from  each sample string. [*grin*] see my answer for one way to handle the data set you posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A single [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_regular_expressions) passed to the `-match` operator should suffice:

```
$arr_services = $allServices | ForEach-Object { 
  if ($_ -match '\((?<word>\w+) *- *(?<number>\d+)') { 
    # Output the word and number consecutively.
    $Matches.word, $Matches.number 
  }
}

# Output the resulting array.
$arr_services
```

<sup>Note how the pipeline output can be directly collected in a variable as an array (`$arr_services = ...`) - no need to iteratively "add" to an array. If you need to ensure that `$arr_services` is *always* an array - even if the pipeline outputs only *one* object, use `[array] $arr_services = ...`</sup>

With your sample strings, the above yields (a flat array of consecutive word-number pairs):

```
targetWord
12434
targetWord
12434
targetWord
12434
targetWord
12434
```

As for the regex:

- `\(` matches a literal `(`
- `\w+` matches a nonempty run (`+`) of word characters (`\w` - letters, digits, `_`), captured in named capture group `word` (`(?<word>...`).
- `*- *` matches a literal `-` surrounded by any number of spaces - including none (`*`).
- `\d+` matches a nonempty run of digits (`\d`), captured in named group `digits`.

if the `-match` operator finds a match, the results are reflected in the [automatic `$Matches` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables#matches), a hashtable that enables accessing named capture groups directly by name.

Comment: Thank you! That was very well described. I do have a question though.
Is "$Matches" as built-in variable to describe the string if -matches returns $true?

Comment: @RedGrinGrumble: Glad to hear it; yes, when `-match` is successful (returns `$true`), `$Matches` is automatically populated - see the link to the docs I've just added to the answer. A caveat is that if the LHS is an _array_, `-match` no longer returns a Boolean and instead acts as a _filter_, and in that case `$Matches` is _not_ populated.

Answer (score 0):

here's one way to handle the data set you posted. it presumes all the strings will have the same general format that you posted. that means it WILL FAIL if your sample data set is not realistic. [*grin*]

```
$InStuff = @(
    'some str (targetWord - 12434 trailing string)'
    'some str (targetWord-12434 trailing string)'
    'some str (targetWord- 12434 trailing string)'
    'some str (targetWord -12434 trailing string)'
    'some str (targetWord-  12434 trailing string)'
    )

$Results = foreach ($IS_Item in $InStuff)
    {
    $Null = $IS_Item -match '.+\((?<Word>.+) *- *(?<Number>\d{1,}) .+\)'
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Word = $Matches.Word.Trim()
        Number = $Matches.Number
        }
    }

$Results
```

output ...

```
Word       Number
----       ------
targetWord 12434 
targetWord 12434 
targetWord 12434 
targetWord 12434 
targetWord 12434
```